# Restrict ERC20 transfer and reception to owners of a particular NFT

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-721, nft

I need to create an ERC20 token which transfer and reception is restricted by a membership, indicated by an NFT (ERC721) in the sender's and receiver's address/wallet.

How can I check in the ERC20 transfer() function whether the sender and receiver are owner of that particular NFT (ERC721, membership)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Open Zeppelin's ERC20 implementation you can reference their [guide](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/extending-contracts#using-hooks) for extending contract functionality.

Alternatively, you can implement the ERC20 functions by hand and add any custom logic you need.

Comment: Thank you very much BrvarG for your advice. How do I technically implement the check in the ERC20 transfer() function, i.e. checking whether the msg.sender owns a particular ERC721 (or any other tokens) in his address?

Comment: Use the function function `_validRecipient(address to, address from) private view returns (bool) {
        // e.g. return myNftContract.ownerOf(tokenId) == to;
    }` that is shown in the guide I linked. You also need to have a reference to an ERC721 contract and a tokenId.